# Google Data Studio - Can I create mutually exclusive fields in a table?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am writing a connector for Google Data Studio. Can I create mutually exclusive fields in a table? For example, if there is a field 1 in the table, then field 2 cannot be added there?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. 
Based from this [documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7512288?hl=en):

> The **Field Editing in Reports** data source option allows report editors
>   to change field definitions at the chart level. Editing field
>   definitions in the report makes customizing your reports faster and
>   easier. It **reduces or even eliminates the need to duplicate fields** in
>   the data source in order to apply different aggregations or functions
>   to the same data. It also allows you to have canonical field
>   definitions in the data source, while tailoring the fields to fit
>   different report requirements.

**Note:** By default, the  field will be defined in the same way in every chart in which it appears. Therefore, you need to enable the field editing reports to change a specific field. You can follow the steps from the documentation for more details.